# APPLICATION FAILED TO START The injection point has the following annotations: @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have created two different project one for API and One for SQL and added SQLConnect project into REST project.

This class in Rest project

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;
    @GetMapping("/person")
    public List<Person> getAllEmployees() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }
    @PostMapping("/addPerson")
    public Person createEmployee(@RequestBody Person person) {
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }
}
```

and bellow Interface in another project project Name is SQLConnect

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>{
}
```

POM File Of Rest project :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!--
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

 local dependencies -->
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.seedq.restinterface</groupId>
     <artifactId>RestInterface</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>com.seedq.sql</groupId>
     <artifactId>SQLConnect</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<!-- local dependencies -->
```

POM file of SQLConnect Project :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Error is:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field personRepository in `com.seedq.rest.controller.PersonController` required a bean of type `'com.seedq.rest.repo.PersonRepository'` that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- `@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)`

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type `'com.seedq.rest.repo.PersonRepository'` in your configuration.

Comment: Did you import the interface PersonRepository in your RestController? Is it in the correct path? seems like you have a problem trying to import it.

Comment: yes it is in correct path

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add either the system path or the url for your local maven project.

```
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/Name_Your_JAR.jar</systemPath>
```

OR

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-maven-repo</id>
        <url>file:///${project.parent.basedir}/local-maven-repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```